# Select cast(0 as bit) in progress returns error "Inconsistent types (7481)"

Tags: sql, openedge

If I were to execute the following statement:

```
select cast(0 as bit) from customer
```

I get the error:

```
[DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Inconsistent types (7481)
```

However, if I were to instead replace the integer literal with a field name such as:

```
select cast(SomeIntField as bit) from customer
```

where `SomeIntField` is an integer field storing `0` or `1` the query executes correctly.

I have noted [progress article #56514](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000056514) but can not contribute an update to inform about accessing a db field.

Comment: You found a bug and a KB article related to the bug. What's your question?

Comment: My question is if there is a known workaround. I don't have any way of contributing feedback to the bug so am posting here for other openedge users feedback. Key to the bug is that it's only related to integer literals and not integer fields. This may help any progress developer understand where the issue may lie.

Comment: Note also that while kb articles exist, progress usually give ridiculous resolutions, like "just don't do it", eg. [kb-28388](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000028388).

Comment: Have you tried "tweaking the sql"? Something like `select cast(cast('0' as int) as bit) from customer`?

Comment: Same result @vmachan. It's no real biggie, just a nuisance really.

Comment: This bug was fixed in 11.6 version of Progress OpenEdge

Comment: Ta @Austin, no plans to ug, we killed our licensing agreement as we were being gouged by progress. Any known workaround? Know if there's a plan to update the kb's to reflect?